# Stop child's background filling in rounded corners of parent

Tags: css

I have a parent div with rounded corners and no padding. The parent div can contain different child divs which each have a background colour.

By default the child's background color extends to the corners and is not limited by the parent's rounded corner. I need the background color not to 'cut off' the rounded corners.

I also need to absolutely position content in the child div outside of the parent div. For this reason I cant just set overflow hidden to the parent div.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogGoMr

```
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    Text
  </div>

</div>

.one {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.two {
  background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Just give the child `border-radius: 10px;` so it matches the parent?

Comment: I could use this solution if required but it will make my CSS less clean.

Comment: I don't see another way (there could be) without using `overflow: hidden;`.

Comment: Using an additional `border-radius` will not make your CSS dirty. You can combine two selectors to use the same `border-radius` rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I offer two ways to do this :

1.Add a `border-radius` to chaild div:

```
.two {
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

**2**.use Padding to parent div and add background same to parent:

see Example:

```css
.one {
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding:0 10px;

    background: blue;
}
.two {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want more divs inside the parent div, that do not 'cut off' the rounded corners, you can set:

```
.one > div:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.one > div:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEeWbN)